# Local variable undefined

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
        for x in results:
            sponsor = x.findAll(class_="s-sponsored-label-info-icon")

            if sponsor == []:

                for each in results:

                    price_data = {
                        'Item Name': each.h2.a.text.strip(),
                        'Item Price': "Not Available",
                        'Discounted Price': "Not Available",
                        'Percentage of discount': 0.0,
                        'Item rating': each.i if each.i is not None else "No rating",
                        'Url': each.find(class_="a-link-normal a-text-normal").get('href')
                    }

                    # To get the types of prices realprice = non discount \ disprice = discounted price
                    hasdisprice = each.find(class_="a-price")
                    hasrealprice = each.find(class_="a-price a-text-price")

                    if hasrealprice is not None and hasdisprice is not None:
                        price_data["Item Price"] = hasrealprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
                        price_data["Discounted Price"] = hasdisprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
                        ogpriceclean = price_data["Item Price"].replace("s$", "")
                        discountpriceclean = price_data["Discounted Price"].replace("s$", "")
                        ogpriceclean = float(ogpriceclean)
                        discountpriceclean = float(discountpriceclean)

                        # Finding discounted percentage
                        price_data["Percentage of discount"] = findpercentage(ogpriceclean, discountpriceclean)
                    elif hasdisprice is None:  # We know hasrealprice is not None
                        price_data["Item Price"] = hasrealprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
                    elif hasrealprice is None:  # We know hasdisprice is not None
                        price_data["Discounted Price"] = hasdisprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
                    else:  # We know both are None
                        pass  # We could assign something here if needed in this case

                    # print(f"Price data={price_data}")  # Uncomment to make sure it looks right

                    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(price_data, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)


        return soup
```

I'm having issues running this program, which raises this error:

[This error which states i'm returning a none after debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCIN0.png)

If I run it without the debugger the following error will arise
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,) into shape (1,)`

I do not know what is causing this error, or how to clean up this code.

Comment: The items also have local variable issues

Comment: If either `hasrealprice` or `hasdisprice` isn't None, then `discountpercentage` isn't assigned a value.  What value do you want it to have in that case?

Comment: Hi there. We don't use `[Solved]` title hacks here. Please either accept an answer below (by ticking it) or write a self-answer and accept/tick that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to use a variable before it has been assigned in the local context. Try to declare it before using it.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't cite a line number that the error arises, it is likely the last line:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Item Name': name, 'Item Price': itemprice, 'Discounted Price': disitemprice,'Percentage of discount': discountpercentage, 'Item rating': itemrating, 'Url': urlitem}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)`
```

Here you assign `discountpercentage`, but this may not have been defined, in particular because of your if/else cases:

```
if hasrealprice is not None and hasdisprice is not None:
    ...
    # discountpercentage gets assigned here
else:
    if hasrealprices is not None:
        ...
        # No assignment here
    else:
        ...
        # or here
    if hasdisprice is not None:
        ...
        # or here
    else:
        ...
        # or here
```

So, part of what is at issue here is that your structure is sort of asking for a lot of copy-paste wiring. What I would recommend is to start with the object that you need to consume in that last line, specifically a dictionary, and then fill it in:

```
for result in results:
    price_data = {
      'Item Name': result.h2.a.text.strip(), 
      'Item Price': "Not Available", 
      'Discounted Price': "Not Available",
      'Percentage of discount': 0.0, 
      'Item rating': each.i if each.i is not None else "No rating", 
      'Url': each.find(class_="a-link-normal a-text-normal").get('href')
    }

    # To get the types of prices realprice = non discount \ disprice = discounted price
    hasdisprice = each.find(class_="a-price")
    hasrealprice = each.find(class_="a-price a-text-price")

    if hasrealprice is not None and hasdisprice is not None:
        price_data["Item Price"] = hasrealprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
        price_data["Discounted Price"] = hasdisprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
        ogpriceclean = float(price_data["Item Price"].replace("s$",""))
        discountpriceclean = float(price_data["Discounted Price"].replace("s$",""))

        # Finding discounted percentage
        price_data["Percentage of discount"] = findpercentage(ogpriceclean, discountpriceclean)
    elif hasdisprice is None:  # We know hasrealprice is not None
        price_data["Item Price"] = hasrealprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
    elif hasrealprice is None:  # We know hasdisprice is not None
        price_data["Discounted Price"] = hasdisprice.find(class_="a-offscreen").text.strip()
    else:  # We know both are None
        pass  # We could assign something here if needed in this case

    # print(f"Price data={price_data}")  # Uncomment to make sure it looks right

    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(price_data, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Try `result` rather than `each`. `each` is not a great name, and you can expect people to generally use `result` as the singular of `results`.